# Ubuntu 20.04 crashes almost every day

Tags: 20.04, crash

I am a new user of Ubuntu 20.04. Since I installed Ubuntu about 2 months ago my Lenovo laptop crashes at least once almost every day. Most of the time it is when I am playing some video from my hard drive, but not necessarily only when I am playing a video.

The screenshot shows shutdown details. The copy/paste version is also provided below.

[image: error_shutdown]

```
$ roguestate@roguestate:~$ cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep -i shutdown
Aug 19 08:09:00 roguestate kernel: [96478.215423] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Aug 19 13:58:42 roguestate kernel: [108569.528199] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Aug 19 14:13:18 roguestate kernel: [108599.937981] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Aug 19 14:21:15 roguestate kernel: [108630.177357] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Aug 19 15:01:51 roguestate kernel: [108660.449433] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Aug 19 21:37:59 roguestate kernel: [117633.918141] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Aug 19 22:37:59 roguestate systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
Aug 19 22:37:59 roguestate systemd[1]: Finished Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
Aug 19 22:37:59 roguestate kernel: [    1.386145] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Aug 19 22:37:59 roguestate systemd[1]: Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
Aug 19 22:37:59 roguestate systemd[1085]: gnome-session-pre.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Aug 19 22:37:59 roguestate systemd[1085]: gnome-session-initialized.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Aug 19 22:37:59 roguestate systemd[1085]: gnome-session-failed.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Aug 19 22:37:59 roguestate systemd[1085]: gnome-session-wayland.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Aug 19 22:38:11 roguestate systemd[1787]: gnome-session-pre.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Aug 19 22:38:11 roguestate systemd[1787]: gnome-session-initialized.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Aug 19 22:38:11 roguestate systemd[1787]: gnome-session-failed.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
Aug 19 22:38:14 roguestate systemd[1085]: Reached target Shutdown running GNOME Session.
Aug 19 22:38:14 roguestate systemd[1085]: Starting Restart DBus after GNOME Session shutdown...
Aug 19 22:38:14 roguestate systemd[1085]: Stopped target Shutdown running GNOME Session.
Aug 19 22:38:14 roguestate systemd[1085]: Started Restart DBus after GNOME Session shutdown.
Aug 19 22:38:24 roguestate systemd[1085]: Reached target Shutdown.
```

```
result of top
```

[image: result of top]

```
result of df -h
```

[image: result of df -h]

Comment: At a terminal type `cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep -i shutdown` and see if the timestamp corresponds to a crash. Then edit your question and copy&paste in those lines so the community can help.

Comment: I don't remember the exact time, but the system crashed twice between 13:30 to 15:30

Comment: OK then remove the word `shutdown` and look for something at those time stamps. Also try typing `df -h` in a terminal and see if you have run out of space on any particular drive or partition especially / as this will help to rule out. And then it would not hurt to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-power-manager` beacuse the power manager often causes crashed in my experience.

Comment: @darth_epoxy Thanks for the help. I did sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-power-manager as suggested. The laptop did not crash for a whole day. Then this morning, I had 4 crashes in total. I found out no crash I experienced was listed in the response of the grep command. I copy/paste the output below:

Aug 21 07:50:01 roguestate kernel: [82814.716115] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds

Aug 21 09:11:36 roguestate kernel: [82844.761324] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds

Aug 21 21:06:06 roguestate kernel: [112999.924770] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds

Comment: Does `df -h` show anything that is running low on space? Try then typing `top` and see if the any particular module is chewing up resources.

Comment: @darth_epoxy Thanks for the help. I have edited the original post to include pictures with result of **df -h** and **top**. I don't see anything out of the ordinary. Is it possible to to see these details for the time of the system crash? Secondly, I have a feeling that the problem maybe is with some driver. Is it possible to check whether all of the drivers are fine or if any driver is causing the trouble?

Comment: Yes I think that rules out memory and processor drain. If a module, driver or firmware was causing it (which it probably is) then I was hoping it would show in the syslog. Hopefully a crash expert will read this and point you in the right direction. Keep checking the syslog or syslog.1 after a crash so you can 100% confirm the events in the log have a timestamp that matches your exact crash time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would keep looking :-)

Comment: Hello people, I am still suffering from this problem. would be grateful for the help. I have stopped watching videos on the laptop so now it doesn't crash that frequently though.

Comment: I think this is your problem but I am not the person who can solve it https://www.reddit.com/r/vivaldibrowser/comments/4k1fc8/linux_vivaldi_high_disk_write_constantly/ sorry